# easeljs background image rect - cover

Tags: createjs, easeljs

I have a shape in easeljs. When it is initially created it has a backgroundcolor set to white. Then, at some point later down the line, I need to give this rectangle shape a background image - I really can't get it to work.

I would like the background image of the shape to be positioned like this:

```
background-image:    url(images/background.svg);
background-size:     cover;                   
background-repeat:   no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
```

Anyone who can tell me how to approach this. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a background image with EaselJS, you can't use CSS.

You can instead use the [bitmapFill](http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Graphics.html#method_beginBitmapFill) with EaselJS graphics, which does a pattern fill using an image.

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = "path/to/image";

var shape = new createjs.Shape();
shape.graphics.beginBitmapFill(img, "optionalRepeat", optionalMatrix);
shape.graphics.drawRect(0,0,100,100);
```

Here is a quick fiddle showing it in action:  http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/ogy1qmxn/2/

Cheers,

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply - I found something like in other threads. The thing is that I would like to make the bitmap behave as if I wrote the CSS I showed in my initial question.

One rectangle with the background image that covers the rectangle according to the same rules as css bgsize cover :) Is that possible.

Comment: You would have to do the math to size/scale the image to cover. Here is a fiddle that determines the "cover" math, and scales the background. It also translates it so it is centered. http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/ogy1qmxn/7/